# Trigonometry, range of a function

Tags: trigonometry

The range of function $\cos(\cos x)$ is

Please explain the whole mathematical procedure to get to the answer,

no hit and trial method please.

Comment: I tried at first by listing the inequality of cosx that it lies between -1 and 1 and then taking cos on both the sides but then the answer comes that cos(cosx) lies between cos1 and cos1 which has no meaning, but the same method works for sine function, why?

Comment: Problems posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  It can make people think you copied a question without understanding it.  If understanding it is what you need help with, then you can ask about that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$ then $\cos x$ goes from $1$ down to $0$, so $\cos(\cos(x))$ goes from $\cos1$ _up_ to $\cos0=1$.  Then as $x$ goes from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ then $\cos x$ goes from $\cos0=1$ back down to $\cos1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $$-1\leq \cos x\leq 1\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Now $$\displaystyle 1\approx \frac{\pi}{3}\;,$$ So we assume that $$\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{3}\approx-1\leq \cos x\leq 1\approx \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Now When we draw graph of $\cos x\;,$ Then we have seen that it is Symmetrical about $x=0$ line

Means it is Symmetrical about $\bf{Y-}$ axis.

So we will draw graph of $$\cos(\cos x)$$ for $0\leq \cos x\leq 1$

and We know that $\cos x$ is an Decreasing function in $0\leq \cos x\leq 1$

So  $$\cos (1) \leq \cos(\cos x)\leq 1$$

And For $\sin$ function it is valid bcz $\sin x$ is an odd function ,

Means it is Symmetrical about $\bf{y=x}$ line.

So for  $-1\leq \sin x\leq 1\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

So $$\sin (-1)\leq \sin (\sin x)\leq \sin (1)\Rightarrow -\sin (1)\leq \sin (\sin x)\leq \sin (1)$$

Comment: It is not symmetrical about x axis

Comment: Sorry $\bf{Y-}$ axis.

Comment: We know that cosine is decreasing function............. Please explain more clearly after that

Comment: For  Strictly Decreasing function $f$, If $a<b\;,$ Then $f(a)>f(b)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that:

$$\cos (x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$$

So the argument (domain) of the outer Cosine lies in the interval $[-1,1]$. Thus:

$$\cos(\cos(x)): [-1,1] \rightarrow [\cos(1),1]$$

because $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $1>\cos(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$ then $\cos x$ goes from $1$ down to $0$, so $\cos(\cos(x))$ goes from $\cos1$ *up* to $\cos0=1$.  Then as $x$ goes from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ then $\cos x$ goes from $\cos0=1$ back down to $\cos1$. The method suggested in your comment would make sense if cosine were everywhere increasing or everywhere decreasing.